# Use parent controller required in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to require two controllers on one of my directives, `ngModel` and my own.

The parent controllers should be injected to the child's link function, but I can't get it to work. I'm wondering what am I doing wrong ...

```
app.directive('container', function () { 
  return { 
    transclude : true ,
    template : "<div ng-transclude></div>",
    controller : function ($scope) { 
      console.log('container controller');
      $scope.v1 = '123';
      $scope.f1 = function () { 
         console.log('f1');
      };
    },
    link : function (scope, element) { 
      console.log('container link');
    }
  };
});

app.directive('single', function () { 
  return { 
    require : ['^container','ngModel'], 
    scope : false , 
    link : function (scope, element, attrs , parentsCtrl) { 
      console.log('single link');
      console.log(parentsCtrl);

      var containerParent = parentsCtrl[0];
      var ngModel = parentsCtrl[1];

      // FAIL //
      console.log(containerParent.v1);
      containerParent.f1();
    }
  };
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div container>
  <input single type="text" ng-model="my.value" />
</div>
```

The `single` directive is injected with both controllers' constructors but the `container` controller is empty. I expected to find `v1` property and `f1` function.

[Full jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/bogozuco/1/edit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `require` the link function accesses the controller object, **NOT the controller's scope**. So this:

```
$scope.v1 = '123'; // WRONG
```

Should really be:

```
this.v1 = '123'; // RIGHT
```

To be accessed as `containerParent.v1`.

Comment: Wow, Thanks Nikos. When started out with angular i throw `this` out the window...